# Is that a way to open a SubPage with the method Window.open ()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is that a way to open a SubPage with the method `Window.open()`?
and then implement a `click` action on the parent page.

Now I have to `re-click` the parent page to trigger the click action, please

```
// my code
$(document).ready(
   function(){
    document.onkeyup = function(){
    var oEvent = window.event;

    //Q--->test submit
    if (oEvent.keyCode == 81) {
        oEvent.preventDefault();       
        $("i.fas.fa-sun").click();
    } 

    //E--->test search
    if (oEvent.keyCode == 69) {
        var searchWord = $("h1.h1").text();
        function openwindow(aa){
            var iHeight = window.screen.availHeight;
            var iWidth = window.screen.availWidth;
            return window.open(aa,'newindow','height='+iHeight+',width='+iWidth/2+',top=0,left=0,toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,location=no,status=no');          
      }
      if(searchWord){
        openwindow("https://www.baidu.com/s?ie=utf-8&f=8&rsv_bp=1&rsv_idx=1&tn=baidu&wd="+ searchWord);
        Google = openwindow("https://www.google.com/search?q="+searchWord);
        // Bing = openwindow("https://cn.bing.com/search?q="+searchWord);
      }
    }

  } 
  
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by a child page?

Comment: I don't think browsers allow that because of security.

Comment: "chil page" is SubPage opened through the method "window.open()"